# does terraform state saves states for different config files?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This is how my current terraform directory looks like, to deploy an ecr repo.

```
├── configs
│   ├── qa-ohio.tfvars
│   ├── qa-ohio.tfvars.template
│   ├── qa-virginia.tfvars
│   └── qa-virginia.tfvars.template
├── ecr.tf
├── provider.tf
└── vars.tf
```

If I run:

```
terraform apply --var-file=configs/qa-virginia.tfvars
```

from the root directory, a new ecr repo is created in us-east-1 (N. virginia region).
if I now run:

```
terraform apply --var-file=configs/qa-ohio.tfvars
```

from the root directory, a new ecr repo is created in us-east-2 (Ohio).
So far so good.

my problem comes now, because the terraform.tfstate is now overwritten by the second command. which means if I run:

```
terraform destroy --var-file=configs/qa-ohio.tfvars
```

it will destroy the repo in ecr (and empty the terraform.tfstate) which is fine, but then if I run:

```
terraform destroy --var-file=configs/qa-virginia.tfvars
```

nothing will happen, because the previous command already removed everything from the terraform.tfstate, so terraform will think there is nothing else to destroy.
I was hoping for the terraform state to be smart enough to know that if we are using different environments variables, then it should keep a different state, which doesn't seem to be the case.
How should I deal with this?

This is how my files looks like:

ecr.tf:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "ecr" {
   name = "web-silver"
}
```

provider.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
  secret_key = "${var.AWS_SECRET_KEY}"
  region = "${var.REGION}"
}
```

vars.tf:

```
variable "AWS_ACCESS_KEY" {}
variable "AWS_SECRET_KEY" {}
variable "REGION" {}
```

qa-virginia.tfvars

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "hidden-for-security-purposes"
AWS_SECRET_KEY = "hidden-for-security-purposes"
REGION = "us-east-1"
```

qa-ohio.tfvars

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "hidden-for-security-purposes"
AWS_SECRET_KEY = "hidden-for-security-purposes"
REGION = "us-east-2"
```

Comment: How are you configuring your state files? Or are you just using local state files?

Comment: local state files.

Comment: This looks heavily like a use case for converting this config into a module, and then declaring it from different configs with different variables. Alternatively, this also looks like a use case for Terraform workspaces, but the module path is more fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is use terragrunt, you can set a custom path for the local backend (using differents configurations for any env)

https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/399